# Optimize little Woocommerce snippet code with IF .. ElseIF and such

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, shipping-method

Would you please help me out to optimize my little snippet I wrote to apply a discount after adding products in the cart with `tech` assigned shipping class and other products with no class specified for WordPress (Woocommerce) website.
How can I optimize the `if .. elseif` and overall make it better. Also, is adding `break` a good practise? I'm a PHP newbie, but I'm currently learning and would like to improve my code. Porbably I can use something similar to `switch`? Any help and examples are greatly appreciated!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjustment_in_rates_of_product_with_shipping_class', 12, 2 );

function adjustment_in_rates_of_product_with_shipping_class( $available_shipping_methods, $package ) {

   // Shipping class slug to be eligible for a discount when combined with no class products
    $shipping_class = array(
        'tech',
    );

   // Discount
    $discounteuro = 3.50;
    $discountgbp = 3.20;
    $discountusd = 4;
    $discountglobalusd = 5;

    // Enter the shipping method value
    $shipping_services = array(
       'flat_rate:5',
    );

    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values) {
        if ( in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class() , $shipping_class) ) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $shipping_class_no_exists = false;
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values) {
        if ( strlen($values['data']->get_shipping_class()) == 0 ) {
            $shipping_class_no_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($shipping_class_exists && $shipping_class_no_exists) {
        foreach ($available_shipping_methods as $key => $value) {
            if ( in_array($value->get_id() , $shipping_services) && get_woocommerce_currency() == 'EUR' ) {
                $available_shipping_methods[$key]->cost -= $discounteuro;
        break;
            }
        elseif ( in_array($value->get_id() , $shipping_services) && get_woocommerce_currency() == 'GBP' ) {
                $available_shipping_methods[$key]->cost -= $discountgbp;
        break;
        }
        elseif ( in_array($value->get_id() , $shipping_services) && get_woocommerce_currency() == 'USD' ) {
                $available_shipping_methods[$key]->cost -= $discountusd;
        break;
       }
        else {
            $available_shipping_methods[$key]->cost -= $discountglobalusd;   
        break;
       }
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I see, so I'll just leave `break` for `$shipping_class_exists` and `$shipping_class_no_exists`, right?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - Thank you a lot. On top of your great approach you posted below with implementing all `elseif`s in just one `if`, do you see a way to improve both `$shipping_class_exists` and `$shipping_class_no_exists` too? Overall, is the rest of the code good? Thank you a lot once again for taking the time to help me out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would combine your first two loops into a single loop, because there isn o reason to loop over the data twice. Something like this

```
$shipping_class_exists = false;
$shipping_class_no_exists = false;

foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values) {
    if(in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class() , $shipping_class)) {
        $shipping_class_exists = true;
    }
    if(strlen($values['data']->get_shipping_class()) == 0) {
        $shipping_class_no_exists = true;
    }
}
```

I would also convert your discounts into an array, to make it easier to call from your loop.

```
$discounts = [
    'EUR' => 3.5,
    'GBP' => 3.2,
    'USD' => 4,
    'globalusd' => 5
];
```

Then your loop would become

```
if ($shipping_class_exists && $shipping_class_no_exists) {
    foreach ($available_shipping_methods as $key => $value) {
        
        //store currency type in an easier to access variable
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();   
        
        //create variable `$discount` defaulting to `$discounts['globalusd']`
        $discount = $discounts['globalusd'];

        if(in_array($value->get_id(), $shipping_services) && array_key_exists($currency, $discounts)) {

            //if $value->get_id()` is in `$shipping_services` and `$currency` key exists in $discounts
            //then alter $discount to the correct value
            $discount = $discounts[$currency];
        }

        //subtract discount from cost        
        $available_shipping_methods[$key]->cost -= $discount;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, however it doesn't do what my code does. If shipping service `flat_rate:5` and store currency `USD`, `EUR`, `GBP` it should do the discount, but if the shipping service is different than it should do the `globaldiscount`. I got confused a bit of what I should edit to your code to behave exactly like mine does. Thanks

Comment: @Korla Changed it up a bit more for that second part, because the Ternary got a little too long for my personal tastes. This looks cleaner. Your issue from your comment should also be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2** *Removed some mistakes*

The following optimized code should do the trick (code is commented):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjustment_in_rates_of_product_with_shipping_class', 12, 2 );

function adjustment_in_rates_of_product_with_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {

    // Shipping class slug to be eligible for a discount when combined with no class products
    $target_shipping_classes = array('tech');

    // Enter the shipping method value
    $shipping_rate_ids       = array('flat_rate:5');

    // Discount based on currency
    $currency_discounts      = array(
        ''      => 5,
        'EUR'   => 3.50,
        'GBP'   => 3.20,
        'USD'   => 4,
    );

    $shipping_class_found    = $other_shipping_classes = $currency_found = false;

    $woocommerce_currency    = get_woocommerce_currency();

    // Loop through cart items for the current package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        $shipping_class = $item['data']->get_shipping_class(); // Get item shipping class

        if ( in_array( $shipping_class, $target_shipping_classes ) ) {
            $shipping_class_found = true;
        }
        elseif ( ! empty($shipping_class) ) {
            $other_shipping_classes = true;
        }
    }

    // When there is only items from the defined shipping classes
    if ( $shipping_class_found && ! $other_shipping_class ) {
        // Loop through available shipping rates in the current shipping package
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( in_array($rate_key, $shipping_rate_ids) ) {
                // Loop through defined currency discounts
                foreach ( $currency_discounts as $currency => $discount ) {
                    if ( $woocommerce_currency === $currency ) {
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost -= $discount;
                        $currency_found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If no currency match, we get the default value (the first one)
                if ( ! $currency_found ) {
                    $rates[$shipping_rate_id]->cost -= reset($currency_discounts);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Note: You should empty your after saving this code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out, but after testing your code, it doesn't work at all. Not sure why is that but there's no discount at all and doesn't behave like my code in the original post.